# Troubleshooting steps for SMPS producing 1.3V instead of 5V

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have an SMPS based on the [TPS563200](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps563200.pdf) regulator. It worked great. Then it parted ways with its magic blue smoke. Why this happened is a separate conversation, not one I understand fully. It was turned on after dozens of other times, and then caught fire, producing this:

[image]

The relevant circuit is as follows:

[image]

Here's the only thing running off the 5V - two servos:

[image]

I replaced the IC with a fresh one, and now I'm getting 1.3V at the output pin. I don't understand smps design enough to be able to figure out what that should be telling me.

What's a logical next step?

The only other components with visible damage on them are the two ceramic caps in the picture, they're input caps and the damage is just soot. Clearly, that's just visible damage and I don't know what else if broken but not visible.

Comment: Check the feedback network. Sounds like R14 or C18 might be a dead short now.

Comment: hm. r14 is measuring at 10K, and R15 at 7K. clearly not what they're supposed to be. I'll swap them out and see, thanks.

Comment: You cannot measure resistors in-circuit. You have to lift at least one pad/pin or remove them altogether. Any additional resistance in parallel with the resistor will cause the in-circuit reading to be lower than actual resistor.

Comment: I am suspecting it is something to do with servo regeneration adding power to Vout and causing over-voltage, or, transient associated with turning off the servos. But really not sure. Anyway, I would check Vout with an oscilloscope and look for any excursions over 5V.

Comment: @mkeith - I'm measuring voltage with the servos disconnected

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no luck. I replaced the entire network and now the voltage oscillates around 500mV.

Comment: What is going on at the feedback pin? Is it steady, unsteady? Is it higher or lower than it is supposed to be? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Also, please explain how it failed. That might give us a better chance at guessing what else may have been damaged.